# Manhunt won't start suddenly on Windows 11

Tags: technical-issues, windows-11, manhunt

My Manhunt (2003) game worked perfectly on Windows 11. I was also able to install some mods and play with them. Until today when I tried to start Manhunt.exe it won't do anything even if I try to start it As Administrator. I don't know what may cause this issue. I also have installed fixer.

Is it possible that some antivirus may cause this issue or is there some features of Windows preventing start this game?

Comment: Have you tried to disable Anti-virus when you run the game to see? Have you also tried compatibility mode? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-older-apps-or-programs-compatible-with-windows-783d6dd7-b439-bdb0-0490-54eea0f45938#ID0EBH=Windows_11

Comment: @TimmyJim I tried run it in compatibility mode with anti-virus turned off but program didn't start also

Comment: @TimmyJim I also tried this fixer for it : https://github.com/fkortsagin/Manhunt-Windows-11-Fix .But it also didn't work for me. Can problem that some other app is preventing from opening it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **fixed** it! All you need to do is disable **Data Execution Prevention** on your system. **(I tested it on **Windows 11**)**

It is located in here:

1. *Search bar* - >
2. *type in "advanced"* ->
3. *View Advanced System Settings* - >
4. On **Performance** Section click **Settings** - >
5. **Data Execution Prevention** ->

On window here I had **Manhunt.exe** so I **removed it** from here
and checked *Turn on DEP for essential Windows program and services only* -> **Click Apply** and then **OK**. Then I **restared my computer** and **voila Manhunt.exe runs again as usual**.